# Can I cast a primitive from NSDictionary valueForKey?

Tags: ios

I have a int variable which represents a catalogid. The variable is declared outside the block like the following:

```
int catalogId = [vegetableService getCurrentCatalogNumber];
```

Inside the block I do something like this:

```
 int serverCatalogId = (int) [obj valueForKey:@"CatalogId"];

                if(catalogId < serverCatalogId)
                {   
                    catalogId = serverCatalogId;
                }
```

This of course results with an error saying that the variable must of type __block. So I declared the catalogid like this:

```
__block int catalogId = [self getCurrentCatalogNumber];
```

But now I get weird values like 196758 instead of 1,2,3.

Comment: lots of things could be going on here.  But ints cant be stored in obj C collections casting a pointer to NSNumber as if it were an int is not going to work.

Comment: Seems like it is not blocks fault but my web service is sending int values which are somehow represented by those large numbers.

Comment: I thought you might be getting some bad input.  Is autoboxing of NSNumber really supported?  You are casting an int out of what I assume is an NSDictionary, you cant store ints in NSDictionary so Im wondering how thats working

Comment: I am voting to close this question since it is not really related to blocks! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
int serverCatalogId = (int) [obj valueForKey:@"CatalogId"];
```

This is casting a pointer to an int.  Hence crazy values.  Primitives can not be stored in objective C collections.  If you have this elsewhere in your system, look at NSNumber and use its type conversion method intValue to pull an NSNumber out of an NSDictionary.